# Geting an error 1004 using OnAction in a shape

Tags: excel, vba

Ive been searching a lot of this error and couldnt find the solution,getting the following error:

> Error 1004 defining Application  or Object

Using the following code:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Shapes(shapeName).OnAction = macroName
```

- its all in a simple workbook with one sheet.
- any external macros
- sheet/shape is not locked
- shapeName and macroName its simple strings

More information:

```
Call SetButtonActive("get_quest_1", "GetQuest")

Function SetButtonActive(shapeName As String, macroName As String)
    Sheets("sheet1").Shapes(shapeName).OnAction = macroName
    Sheets("sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array(shapeName)).ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset41
    With Sheets("sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array(shapeName)).Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: What kind of shape are we talking about? Are you still working with ActiveX (per your previous questions)?

Comment: Could it be a workbook reference? the code is working perfectly for me. Unless you got wrong your `ShapeName` or your `macroName`

Comment: Shapes = Insert>Forms>Rectangle. shapeName and macroname matchs... macroName is another Sub

Comment: its a rectangle that im providing a click action (OnAction)

Comment: @BigBen it is not, just a rectangle from the insert tab under shapes. I'm sorry William but with the code provided I've tested it myself and works just fine... There must be something with your variables or maybe you are trying to run the macro with more than one workbook and it's no referencing the good one.

Comment: Using the RecordMacro from excell: 
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("go_quest_1")).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "GoQuest"

Comment: So.. is your `shapeName = "go_quest_1"` and your `macroName = "GoQuest"` ?

Comment: yes... it is...

Comment: @WilliamCezar could it be a workbook reference? Try and reference also the workbook.

Comment: @Damian same error with Workbooks("pk") or ActiveWorkbook

Comment: Please put the variables in the watches window or watch the local window when you step through (using `F8`) your code. Some variable is a mis-match and I bet that it's `"go_quest_" & QUEST_PRESSED` that's causing it.

Comment: i removed all variables and set to strings.. and put the line at the start of the sub.. Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("get_quest_1").OnAction = "GetQuest" still same error

Comment: How many shapes have you got on your sheet? Run a short script to see the actual names of these shapes > `For each shp in Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes .....Debug.print shp.name.....Next shp` and check if the one you refer to is actually there. Allthough that would (on my end) result in a different error.

Comment: a LOT..........

Comment: hm i kinda figuring out... i broke all conections of a shape and worked.. but now i have this button that is not conected to the main shape..

Comment: how do i refer this shape into a grouped shape?

Comment: @William Cezar - record a macro, while grouping the shape and change the color of the group. The code would be rather ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MacroName` should be in inverted commas, the following has worked:

```
Sub TestMe()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes(1).OnAction = "MacroName"
End Sub

Sub MacroName()
    Debug.Print "TEST"
End Sub
```

Comment: i really dont understand your answer... using " " im passing a string.. and i have to use a variable

Comment: @William Cezar - strange. It worked by me with exactly that code. Can you open a new Excel and add 1 shape, then run the code?

Comment: well, its not because MacroName IS the MacroName string?